# Linux Shell Script - How to get the upper directory of a parameter $n

Tags: linux, bash, shell, parameters, directory

in my script I receive as parameter **$1** a .tgz file and I have to filter the size of its elements in a temporal directory, create a new one and rewrite the original.

If **$1** is ***"~/Directory/File.tgz"***, I need to know hot to get to *"~/Directory"* so I can work with it.

This is my code:

```
dtemp=`mktemp -d ./tmpdirXXX`
    cp $1 $dtemp #Copy
    cd $dtemp
    comprimido=`find ./ -name "*.tgz"`
    tar xzvf $comprimido
    rm $comprimido

    for archivo in *
    do
        Tarchivo=`du -b "$archivo" | cut -f1`
        if test 70192 -lt $Tarchivo
        then
            echo "$archivo es mayor de 8KB"
            rm -r $archivo
        fi
    done

    tar czvf $1 $dtemp
    rm -r $dtemp
```

The last two lines don't work, it says that the file or directory doesn't exist.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `dirname "$1"` would give you the directory name.

Comment: For assigning to a variable, say `dir=$(dirname "$1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last two lines don't work because you `cd`'d to the temp directory, but never `cd`'d back.